# Why and how does the plyr package use undefined functions?

Tags: r, function, plyr

The question title may betray some misconception which you're welcome to point out.  Nonetheless, there is something mysterious about some of the `plyr` functions.  For example, look at the `laply` function, which is scripted as:

```
function (.data, .fun = NULL, ..., .progress = "none", .inform = FALSE, 
    .drop = TRUE, .parallel = FALSE, .paropts = NULL) 
{
    if (is.character(.fun)) 
        .fun <- do.call("each", as.list(.fun))
    if (!is.function(.fun)) 
        stop(".fun is not a function.")
    if (!inherits(.data, "split")) 
        .data <- as.list(.data)
    res <- llply(.data = .data, .fun = .fun, ..., .progress = .progress, 
        .inform = .inform, .parallel = .parallel, .paropts = .paropts)
    list_to_array(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .drop)
}
<environment: namespace:plyr>
```

The last call, which formats the result, uses a function `list_to_array`.  That function is not defined inside `laply` and neither does it exist outside (check `exists("list_to_array")`).  Yet `laply` works (of course - and I have used it personally)!  How is this possible?

I would like to know how `laply` combines list elements to an array so I can know how efficient it is.  There are alternative ways, for example `do.call(rbind, res)` (in the 2D case).  Knowing how `laply` does this would help me make an informed decision.

Other examples include (non-exhaustively): `splitter_a` within `aaply` and `alply`, `splitter_d` within `ddply` and `list_to_dataframe` within `ldply`.  By contrast, `simplify2array` in `sapply` is explicitly defined outside `sapply`, and is occasionally useful on its own.

Comment: It is defined - but not exported. You can call it using `plyr:::list_to_array` etc. But it will be hard to find documentation.

Comment: Check `getAnywhere(list_to_array)`. Maybe read [how R searches and finds stuff](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/). Packages have their own namespaces where they can create non-exported functions. Those functions are generally not intended to be called directly by the user.

Comment: @Joshua It's not really asking the same question.  `.Primitive` and other functions mentioned are obviously referring to some internal code.  This question is about functions using R scripting but that weren't obviously present in any environment.  Turns out they're there, but at a deeper level.

Comment: Now it's asking the same question. :)

Comment: Well, neither question has changed....